# Create new Wave via URL/JavaScript

Tags: google-wave

I'm trying to imitate the behavior of "mailto:" for creating a new Wave. Does anyone know if it is possible to create a link or write a JavaScript code that would create a new Wave, assuming the user has already logged in to the Google Account?

I've been searching for documentation about this, but everything out there required the Wave API which isn't valid for my needs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so the wave embed api which can be invoked from javascript, unfortunately doesn't let you create new waves at this time. You can open an existing wave though.

you could call out to a server-side script using ajax which will create a wave, then access it using the [wave embed api](http://code.google.com/apis/wave/embed/guide.html) ?

Comment: The solution you suggest would work, but sadly, not for me. Currently, it is not possible for me to involve server side code in my project.
Thanks anyway.